# Change notifier provider is not updating the consumer in main

Tags: flutter, dart, listener, provider

I am trying to set the theme of my app on the response of login data after getting the role but my theme is not updating as per expectation. this is how my main() looks. my code is showing no error and I tried to debug nothing seems wrong.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeModel>(
        create: (_) => ThemeModel(),
        child: Consumer<ThemeModel>(
            builder: (context, ThemeModel themeNotifier, child) {
          return Sizer(builder: (context, orientation, deviceType) {
            return MaterialApp(
              theme: themeNotifier.theme == 'consultant'
                  ? counsultantApptheme()
                  : themeNotifier.theme == 'rmo'
                      ? rmoApptheme()
                      : counsultantApptheme(),
              navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              initialRoute: startroute.toString(),
              routes: routes,
            );
          });
        }));
```

and this how I am updating after response of login API

```
 if (snapshot.data!.data!.consultantYN == 'Y') {
                Provider.of<ThemeModel>(context, listen: false).theme =
                    'consultant';
              } else {
                Provider.of<ThemeModel>(context, listen: false).theme = 'rmo';
              }
```

and this is my function where I am setting theme and calling notifyListeners() in class extends by ChangeNotifier

```
//theme_model.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:nmc/widgets/theme_config/theme_preference.dart';

class ThemeModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  late String _theme;
  late ThemePreferences _preferences;
  String get theme => _theme;

  ThemeModel() {
    _theme = 'default';
    _preferences = ThemePreferences();
    getPreferences();
  }
//Switching themes in the flutter apps - Flutterant
  set theme(String value) {
    _theme = value;
    _preferences.setTheme(value);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  getPreferences() async {
    _theme = await _preferences.getTheme();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you trace your code? Is your ````set theme```` getting executed? Is your Future builder ever getting the data and hitting ````if (snapshot.!data)````?

Comment: yes, I debug and confirm my set theme is executing.

Comment: What does your get method look like? Are you taking the value from _theme variable, or _preferences? If your _preferences.setTheme is async, and you are getting the value from there - in rebuild you would still get the old value, since _preferences.setTheme didn't have a chance to run yet.

Comment: I have updated the question add the theme Model class. please have a look I am getting from the _theme variable.